# Unable to Debug following kernel crash triggered via SysRq

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I am getting following Oops message while testing on a device which is running on Linux Kernel 3.4.5 and ARM processor.I am unable to trace the issue.
If you look at call stack , you would see it starting from ret_fast_syscall() , now actually sysrq for Crash has been triggered inside the code but i am not getting from where.How can i find that. I have Lauterbach installed but no idea from where to find which part of kernel code has actually triggered this SysRq.

```
[50728.239318] C0 [             sh] SysRq : Trigger a crash
[50728.239501] C0 [             sh] **************** READ GIC status
[50728.239654] C0 [             sh] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
[50728.239776] C0 [             sh] pgd = ebc9c000
[50728.239929] C0 [             sh] [00000000] *pgd=00000000
[50728.240081] C0 [             sh] Internal error: Oops: 805 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[50728.240234] C0 [             sh] kona_fb: die notifier invoked
[50728.240356] C0 [             sh] Modules linked in: bcmdhd dm_crypt(O) moc_crypto(PO) moc_platform_mod(O) texfat(PO)
[50728.241088] C0 [             sh] CPU: 0    Tainted: P        W  O  (3.4.5-g4192471-dirty #116)
[50728.241271] C0 [             sh] PC is at sysrq_handle_crash+0x14/0x20
[50728.241424] C0 [             sh] LR is at __handle_sysrq+0xa0/0x14c
[50728.241516] C0 [             sh] pc : [<c026ad48>]    lr : [<c026b210>]    psr: 60000093
[50728.241516] C0 [             sh] sp : ebd0ff20  ip : 0000000c  fp : 4003a404
[50728.241821] C0 [             sh] r10: 4070002c  r9 : edbc2f0c  r8 : 00000000
[50728.241912] C0 [             sh] r7 : 60000013  r6 : 00000063  r5 : 00000007  r4 : c0a26b90
[50728.242065] C0 [             sh] r3 : 00000001  r2 : 00000000  r1 : c07ab3a2  r0 : 00000063
[50728.242248] C0 [             sh] Flags: nZCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[50728.242401] C0 [             sh] Control: 10c53c7d  Table: adc9c06a  DAC: 00000015
[50728.242492] C0 [             sh]
.................. (Register Contents).............

[50728.284851] C0 [             sh] Stack: (0xebd0ff20 to 0xebd10000)
[50728.284942] C0 [             sh] ff20: 00000002 c026b2bc ec2a4ef0 ebd0ff88 00000002 c026b2e0 edbc2ec0 c014c840
[50728.285125] C0 [             sh] ff40: 00000002 ec2a4ef0 4070002c ebd0ff88 00000002 ebd0e000 00000000 c0109d24
[50728.285308] C0 [             sh] ff60: ec2a4ef0 4070002c ec2a4ef0 4070002c 00000000 00000000 00000002 c0109f5c
[50728.285491] C0 [             sh] ff80: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000003 00000002 00000001 00000004
[50728.285675] C0 [             sh] ffa0: c000e304 c000e140 00000003 00000002 00000001 4070002c 00000002 ffffffff
[50728.285858] C0 [             sh] ffc0: 00000003 00000002 00000001 00000004 4070002c 00000000 406ffc84 4003a404
[50728.286010] C0 [             sh] ffe0: 40035f38 bea5e710 40020257 40150e44 20000010 00000001 00000000 00000000
[50728.286224] C0 [             sh] [<c026ad48>] (sysrq_handle_crash+0x14/0x20) from [<c026b210>] (__handle_sysrq+0xa0/0x14c)
***[50728.286376] C0 [             sh] [<c026b210>] (__handle_sysrq+0xa0/0x14c) from [<c026b2e0>] (write_sysrq_trigger+0x24/0x34)
[50728.286560] C0 [             sh] [<c026b2e0>] (write_sysrq_trigger+0x24/0x34) from [<c014c840>] (proc_reg_write+0x80/0x94)
[50728.286682] C0 [             sh] [<c014c840>] (proc_reg_write+0x80/0x94) from [<c0109d24>] (vfs_write+0xb0/0x128)
[50728.286865] C0 [             sh] [<c0109d24>] (vfs_write+0xb0/0x128) from [<c0109f5c>] (sys_write+0x38/0x64)
[50728.287048] C0 [             sh] [<c0109f5c>] (sys_write+0x38/0x64) from [<c000e140>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)***
[50728.287200] C0 [             sh] Code: e3a03001 e5823000 f57ff04f e3a02000 (e5c23000)
[50728.287384] C0 [             sh] ---[ end trace 1b75b31a2719ed7e ]---
[50728.287475] C0 [             sh] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

Comment: Isn't `kona_fb: die notifier invoked` your answer?

Comment: Well I am not sure.Are you?

Comment: Is `kona_fb` a process or a driver?  If it is a process, then it is the answer.  However, it may be a *frame buffer* driver and it  registers a *die* notifier.  It could be that this notifier has a bug.  The call stack looks like an actual *sysrq* as auselen notes.  If you have a serial port hooked up to nothing, then it may get a *break* and the character to die.  There is no *process* needed if you have `sysrq` and a serial console.  I don't know what the call stack would look like.  It seems like */proc/sysrq-trigger*.  Put break points in *drivers/tty/sysrq.c*.

Answer (score 2):

```
[50728.239318] C0 [             sh] SysRq : Trigger a crash
```

Someone at userland triggered a crash as you would do via `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.

Comment: Yeah that i know, but i dont know who has triggered it.So is there any way for getting to know that. I mean there has to be someway for debugging this kind of generic kernel oops issue, isn`t?

Comment: So Am i missing on some logs, because this is what all the Oops message is, other logs which are before and after this section of Oops message will help me in this??

Comment: [50723.751007] C0 [    kworker/u:0] [THROTTLE]:PMU Die Temp 336

Comment: Aboe line is the line just above the starting of SysRq Trigger Message, actually there were many logs about some Power Management Statics before that.

Comment: Or Let me ask one another question , Can you tell what actually the function ret_fast_syscall does , who and when calls it?

Comment: @randomization I don't know why but sysrq-trigger doesn't tell you who requested the crash. Generally you see it in logs, or if you get a dump you use crash (http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/) but you would need some facilities to capture kernel dump.

Comment: @randomization `ret_fast_syscall` is related to system calls. so some one is making a call to kernel most definitely a write, to sysrq-trigger as we already know. So all that stack is actually tells you how sysrq-trigger works :) That particular trace has nothing to do with calling process.

Comment: Ok ,So you mean that some task (process) was running into the CPU and then somehow it triggered a sysrq crash by issuing a write to /proc/sysrq-trigger file and current running process left the CPU and the task corresponding for handling this sysrq trigger gto the CPU and then kernel crashed and current context of the system was registered to the latter task.So, Am I correct in saying this.

Comment: Now my doubt is, is there any other way using the crash utility by red hat i can find out which was the process executed just before this.Because if I do sys command or bt commad it will show the sysrq  task not the task which has called it.

Comment: @randomization process issued sysrq-trigger is still alive, since write is blocking. So if you can look into kernel guts, you'll clearly see. http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/help_pages/waitq.html

Comment: Well I am unable to see using waitq.Following is the errorcomming   crash> waitq edbe7040
waitq: invalid kernel virtual address: 2  type: "list entry"
crash>

Comment: And also I can find out the process using ps also,isn`t I mean the PPID of current context task would the PID of the required process, isn`t?

Comment: @randomization I you have Lauterbach JTAG attached and configured why don't you use that?  It is a much better option than using the crash utility.

Comment: what's this 'pgd' thing that is causing the actual null? not from the kona_fb trying flip a buffer is it?